# Trie search tree vs ternary search tree for autocomplete?

Tags: java, data-structures, trie, ternary-tree

I'm trying to implement a datastructure such that it'll give autocompleted words when the user writes something. So far I've implemented a trie properly, and the autocomplete works quite fast. Thing is, when loading all the information needed, it uses a bonkers amount of memory.
I've generally seen that many people say that tries are faster but less space efficient, and vice versa for a ternary tree.
I've got an alphabet of about 55-60 characters and am expecting about 800k - 1.2 million words inserted into the tree. Is this just generally a way too large amount of insertions into the trie to work well, space wise? Would switching it to a ternary tree be smarter, memory wise? And would it, if switched to a ternary tree, be "annoyingly" slow to search in?

Thanks!

Comment: [Even though the TRIE Data Structure is an efficient means for implementing large collection of words, they are not regarded as much efficient as implementing all the words in a Dictionary will require 26 Nodes in a standard TRIE.](https://iq.opengenus.org/autocomplete-with-ternary-search-tree/)

Comment: [To overcome this problem, Ternary Search Trees were conceptualized and developed where the child nodes of a TRIE Data Structure are optimized as a Binary Search Tree (BST). Ternary Search Trees are seen as a low-memory alternative to the traditional TRIE Data Structure and can store all the words in an English Dictionary at only 3 words per node.](https://iq.opengenus.org/autocomplete-with-ternary-search-tree/)

Comment: Patricia trees, under "variants" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree